# Unsatisfied Dependency Exception in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a properties XML file as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="sample.findAll">
        <![CDATA[
            The SQL query goes here
        ]]>
    </entry>    
</properties>
```

And a config file as following :

```
@ImportResource("classpath:sql/find-all-sample-native-query.xml")
@Configuration
public class SampleFindAllConfig {

    @Value("#{sample.findAll}")
    private String findAllQuery;

    @Bean
    public String findAllSampleNativeQuery() {
        return findAllQuery;
    }
}
```

I'm injecting the Bean in the DAO class as following :

```
@Inject
private String findAllAnomalieNativeQuery;
```

But I get this error when I run my application :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sampleDAO': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'findAllSampleNativeQuery'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sampleFindAllConfig': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'findAllQuery'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression
>   parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
>   Property or field 'sample' cannot be found on object of type
>   'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' -
>   maybe not public?

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Honestly I'm not comfortable with you using an XML file for this; have you attempted to do this with a properties file instead?

Comment: @Makoto no I haven't I'll try to do it with properties file.

Comment: why are you not leveraging your POJO with the properties file itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the code.

> **Problem 1**: Use `@PropertySource` to load with property values with `@Value`

`@ImportResource` imports beans definitions, usually in conjunction with XML Spring configuration.

To load property values for `@Value` from a configuration file, use `@PropertySource`.

> **Problem 2**: Reference properties using the `${...}` syntax

`#{sample.findAll}` is a SpEL expression. It asks Spring to evaluate `sample.findAll`, using `sample` as a bean. Since there is no bean of that name in the context, Spring rightly complains that there is no such bean.

To load the value of the property `sample.findAll` from a configuration source, use the syntax `${sample.findAll}`.

---

The following code will work:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:sql/find-all-sample-native-query.xml")
public class SampleFindAllConfig {
    @Value("${sample.findAll}")
    private String findAllQuery;

    @Bean
    public String findAllSampleNativeQuery() {
        return findAllQuery;
    }
}
```